# Finding amount of certain item in the hashmap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a method, which I use to count the items in a hashmap:

```
public void getAvailable(final Item item) {
    System.out.println("\n" + "Item's \"" + item.getItemName() + "\" stock");
    System.out.println("Name\tPrice\tAmount");
    for (Map.Entry<Item, Integer> entry : stockItems.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "\t" + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

But if I have specified the key `item`, how can I find the amount of all the items with that key in the hashmap? At the moment it returns me all the items with different keys.

Comment: Isn't there just a _single_ item with the key `item`? Or is `item` only _part_ of the key?

Comment: `stockItems.get(item)` will give you what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the following acheive what you're after?

```
public int getAvailable(final Item item) {
    int count = 0;
    String itemName = item.getItemName();
    for (Map.Entry<Item, Integer> entry : stockItems.entrySet()) {
        Item i = entry.getKey();
        if(itemName.equals(i.getItemName())) {
          count += entry.getValue();
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

EDIT: edited count to start at 0

Comment: Why `int count = 1;`? You should initialize it with 0.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant, but as the previous comment mentioned, the count should be initialized with 0 to give the wanted result.

Answer (score 1):

`how can I find the amount of all the items with that key in the hashmap?`

`Hash Map` key is unique value. You will have only one `value` for any `key`.

Comment: I rather meant to say with the same value, for example if there is an item named Milk in the hashmap with the quantity of 1 and item named Milk in the hashmap with the quantity of 3, then it returns me total of 4.

Comment: @danrodi so the items have the same name but are still different? If so, what makes the difference?

Answer (score 1):

I have to guess what you're trying to achieve so I assume the following:

- your map keys are instances of `Item`
- you only have the key `item` and want to find the corresponding entry in the map

What you could do is:

1. use a separate map to the the `Item` instance for the key and use it to access the counts map
2. create a "dummy" (lookup) item which only gets the data which is used in the `equals()` and `hashCode` methods and use that to access the counts map

Example for 1.:

```
 Map<String, Item> items = ...;

 Integer quantity = stockItems.get(items.get("item"));
```

Example for 2.:

```
class Item {
  private String key;
  public Item(String key) {
    this.key = key;
  }
  ...

  //equals() and hashCode() should only use the key field
}

Integer quantity = stockItems.get( new Item("item") );
```

**Update**:

If the key is not the only attribute of an item, you'd have to iterate over all entries in the map, check the item's key for a match and create the sum yourself.

Answer (score 0):

a key is unique in a hashmap. so there can be only one value with your speicified key.